# Django how to change static dir

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Default dir for static folder is `project/app/static` but since I'm using some js and css libs and I have multiple apps I don't want my project gain some extra size. I wonder if I could move the static folder outside of the app folder. Like:

```
| project
| | app
| | static
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `static` root at `BASE` root then you can go with this config

##### settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

##### Project directory

[image]

NOTE - using **`STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']`** you can set custom **static root**,

only you need to set static folder relative path in **`STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'relative path of sttic folder']`**